# Steady state density of Langevin SDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have the SDE
$$dX_t = -U’(X_t) dt+\sqrt{2} D dW_t$$
where $D>0$. This has Fokker-Planck equation
$$\partial_t p =-\partial_x \left[-U’(x) p(t,x)\right]+\partial_{xx} \left[D^2 p(t,x)\right]$$
and to find the steady state density
$$f(x)=\lim_{t\to \infty} p(t,x)$$
we take the limit as $t\to \infty$ and assume $\partial_t p(t,x)\to 0$. This yields the ODE
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ U’(x) f(x)\right] +D^2 f’’(x)=0.$$

**My question**
How do we solve this ODE to show the steady state is given by
$$f(x) \propto e^{-U(x)/D^2} ?$$

**My attempt**
Note we can “factor” out a derivative to write
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ U’(x)f(x)+D^2 f’(x) \right]=0$$
which implies the expression inside the parentheses must be constant, i.e.
$$D^2 f’(x) +U’(x) f(x) =C$$
and we can solve this using the integrating factor method, so that
$$f(x)= C_1 e^{-U(x)/D^2}+\frac{C}{D^2} e^{-U(x)/D^2} \int e^{-U(x)/D^2} dx$$
How do I conclude that $C=0$ from here? For we must have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx <\infty$ so we can normalize, a la Boltzmann statistics, but I can’t see the justification. Or perhaps I made a mistake. An alternative derivation is okay but I would prefer to see how this is corrected/finished. Thank you.

Comment: After a little more thorough searching, I found the reasoning here, which I’ll quote into an answer when I get time. Essentially, since (first few) moments and total probability must be finite for this model, we must have $C=0$, otherwise the probability flux (the LHS of the ODE) does not decay to zero at infinity: https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~dmarendu/ASP/Section16.pdf

Comment: I also have the same question. Could you please explain a little bit why finite total probability is related to $C=0$? It seems like $f(x) \propto e^{-U(x)/D^2 + Cx/D^2}$ is also one solution and holds for LHS of the ODE.

Comment: @EddieLin yes you might find other functions that solve the ODE but if $C\neq 0$ in your case then we have $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) =\infty$ so it cannot be a PDF. So the only sensible solution for probability theory is when $C=0$.

Comment: @EddieLin I can’t reconcile your example at the moment, but more precisely I meant to write $f$ and $f’$ must decay at $\pm \infty$ to zero for $f$ to have total probability $1$ and finite moments (specifically decay faster than $|x|^{-n-1}$). But $\lim_{x \to \infty} D^2 f’(x)+U’(x) f(x) =C$ so $C=0$ and the flux must be zero everywhere. This is the reasoning in the link in my first comment. Ill look into your example later, sorry swamped with work right now.

Comment: (My last comment might be a little loose with the behavior of $U’(x)$ but I think that can be reconciled)

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for your explanation!